# To set current working directory in PyDev interactive console

Tags: console, pydev

I know that when I start the interactive console in pydev using ctrl + alt + enter, the working directory is not the one the project is in.  Therefore, I adopted this code when the console starts (which worked):

`import sys; print('%s %s' % (sys.executable or sys.platform, sys.version))
import os
cwd_path = [path for path in sys.path if 'org.python.pydev' not in path and 'Python3' not in path and 'python33.zip' not in path]
if len(cwd_path) == 1:
    os.chdir(cwd_path[0])`

However, the problem is it only takes me to the folder of the project, instead of the file. For example, my file is in src//com/main//test//Test.py , and this code will only take me to the folder where src is in.  Is there anyway to get around this?

Thanks!

-Shawn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not technically a work-around, but I do find that Spyder IDE solves this problem pretty well.  I just installed from the WinPython package, and it worked very well for me.

The link to [WinPython](http://code.google.com/p/winpython/)

I'll still really appreciate it if someone can provide a way to fix it in Eclipse/Pydev - because that's been what I use for all other projects and I really like it. Thanks!